# Youtube URL to embed

Tags: php, youtube

I have searched and seen many solutions on stackoverflow, but none of them worked for me. I have a string with youtube URLs

```
<b>This is a youtube video http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0xnKzTqrqrE and here is another one  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0xnKzTqsdds </b> I am not sure if it will work.
```

and I want all youtube URLs to be replaced with

```
<iframe src="http://youtube.com/embed/"> </iframe>
```

There could be more than 1 video url and I want all of them to be converted without changing rest of the string.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest case you could replace:

```
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=([a-zA-Z0-9]{11})
```

by

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Here as php code:

```
echo preg_replace('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=([a-zA-Z0-9]{11})', '<iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/$1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>', $input);
```